# Out of memory (allocated 908066816) (tried to allocate 805306376 bytes) PHP Error Message

Tags: php, arrays, xampp

I created a PHP Algorithm and the code for this algorithm which makes every permutation of letters and numbers is this:

```
    <?php
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time',-1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); 
function florg ($n, $elems) {
    if($n > 0){
        $tmp_set = array();
        $res = florg($n-1, $elems);
        foreach ($res as $ce) {
            foreach ($elems as $e) {
                array_push($tmp_set, $ce . $e);
            }
        }
        return $tmp_set;
    }
    else{
        return array('');
    }
}
$elems = array('q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','z','x','c','v','b','n','m','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0');
$v = FlOrG(7, $elems);
foreach($v as $child) {
    print $child . "\n";
}
?>
```

Basically what it does, is to make a 7 character text using all possible combinations of letters and numbers on keyboard.

So because this program is a little bit huge, I added these 3 lines at the top of the page:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time',-1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Now whenever I run this program on XAMPP, I get this error message:

**Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 908066816) (tried to allocate 805306376 bytes) on line 11**

And here is line 11:

> array_push($tmp_set, $ce . $e);

So I don't understand the relation between this error and this line! I also ran this program online on my web hosting service, but again got the same error message.

I think the code looks fine, therefore my question is how can I run this program ? What is the problem with `array_push()` in this code ?

I would really appreciate any help or idea from you guys cause I've been had this problem for weeks...

Comment: The script just consumes too much resources? Having a bigger computer could help.

Comment: @hakre yes i just run this script.. this  is much big. becuase it is combing letters one by one with them another one. it is taking 10 minutes for `florg(7)` in my server to execute whole script

Comment: @hkre What do u mean by bigger computer? You mean larger amount of RAM or CPU or something else?

Comment: More CPU to run faster into the error and more RAM to find out how much RAM it needs.

Comment: You're trying to create 36^7 (78364164096) 7 value arrays so probably trying to use around 2TB of memory. It's going to take a pretty big computer just to compute that. As for `print`ing it to a display...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to replace [`array_push($array, $value)`](https://php.net/array_push) with same-effect-having `$array[] = $value` notation like in your example:

```
foreach ($res as $ce) {
    foreach ($elems as $e) {
        $tmp_set[] = $ce . $e;
    }
}
```

and variable `$v = florg(7, $elems);`

in this 7 is a big so, and it is combining the values from each other so, first try to add small number than check one by one. like

```
florg(1,$elems);
florg(2,$elems);
florg(3,$elems);
```

and so on.

Hope this will helps you

Comment: I can imagine this could help a little w/ newer PHP versions, but in the end (and also for newer PHP versions), I don't see how it can reduce the memory consumption.